# KOMA-script: set police style within section titles

Tags: fonts, luatex, koma-script, section-titles

Using Lualatex in conjunction with KOMA-script and a custom police (Heofler Text), I had to manually specify which file corresponded with `BoldItalicFont`. However, this is not taken into account within sections titles (which I take to be in bold by default).

```
\documentclass{scrarticle}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\fontspec{Hoefler Text}}
\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}[BoldItalicFont={Hoefler Text Black Italic}]

\begin{document}

\section{The word \textit{cat} should be in italics}

The word \textit{\textbf{cat}} is correctly in bold italic.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `\fontspec{Hoefler Text}` you are not using the later defined main font:

```latex
\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}[BoldItalicFont={Hoefler Text Black Italic}]
```

but just `Hoefler Text`. `fontspec` does not recognize, that this is the same font and that you could mean, that the same bold italic font should be used too. Compare, e.g.,

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}[BoldItalicFont={Hoefler Text Black Italic}]

\begin{document}

The word \textit{\textbf{cat}} is correctly in bold italic.

\fontspec{Hoefler Text}
The word \textit{\textbf{cat}} is correctly not in bold italic.

\end{document}
```

[image: article example does also not show the font]

So you would need to add the optional argument again and use

```latex
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\fontspec{Hoefler Text}[BoldItalicFont={Hoefler Text Black Italic}]}
```

But there is an easier method. If you just want to use the bold main font, you can set element `disposition` to `\bfseries` as shown in the KOMA-Script manual.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries}
\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}[BoldItalicFont={Hoefler Text Black Italic}]

\begin{document}

\section{The word \textit{cat} is in italics}

The word \textit{\textbf{cat}} is correctly in bold italic.

\end{document}
```

[image: solution]

But maybe you even don't want KOMA-Script to use any sans serif defaults for the font elements. In this case, you can use option `sfdefaults=false`:

```latex
\documentclass[sfdefaults=false]{scrartcl}[2023/04/17]

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}[BoldItalicFont={Hoefler Text Black Italic}]

\begin{document}

\section{The word \textit{cat} is in italics}

The word \textit{\textbf{cat}} is correctly in bold italic.

\end{document}
```

The result would be the same.